# codeigniter how to retrieve data from two tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables :

```
users: id, name, email

user_experience: id_exp, user_id, exp_date
```

There are multiple users and each user has multiple experiences.

E.g.

users:

```
1, david, david@david.com
```

is linked to three experiences

```
user_experience:

1, 1, 1/1/2012
2, 1, 2,2,2012
3, 1, 3,3,2012
```

How can I retrieve the data so I can display it in a view like so:

```
Name   / email            / Date of experience

david, david@david.com    1/1/2012

                          2/2/2012

                          3/3/2012

joe,   joe@joe.com        1/1/2012

                          2/2/2012

                          3/3/2012
```

My code currently:

Controller

```
$data['nurses'] = $this->users_model->get_nurse();
```

Model

```
public function get_nurse() {
    $this->db->select('name,email,date');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('user_experience', 'users.id = user_experience.user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
echo $row['first_name'];
echo $row['email'];
echo $row['exp_date'];
```

This however displays a new line for each user and exp combo. I want the user displayed only once. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your get nurse function shouldn't include experiences as they are separate entities.
Have get nurse return just the nurses info, and then for each nurse get_experiences() and display those. So your controller would look something like this.

```
$data['nurses'] = $this->users_model->get_nurse();
foreach($data['nurses'] as $nurseObj) {
   $expM = new ExperienceModel($nurseObj->id);
   // Display/pass/generate nurse info
   $nurse_experiences = $expM->getExperiences();
   foreach($nurse_experiences as $ne) {
        // experience info
   }
}
```